# how to convert ascii fonts to unicode for translation

Tags: android, ios, unicode, fonts, ascii

I am developing an android and ios app which will be translated in multiple languages including english, hindi and gurmukhi. We have some pdf files in Gurmukhi that use ASCII fonts instead of unicode and we need to translate them to other languages so that when we try to copy the text we end up with some weird text. Is there a way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every symbol font has its own repertoire, so you need a custom lookup table from the ‘wrong’ character to the real character corresponding to what the glyph looks like in the particular font you are using. You can work out this table by installing the font in question and opening it in the Character Map (charmap.exe), noting down which symbol appears in each of the boxes normally occupied by `A`, `B`, `C`...

There is a converter tool [here](http://punjabi.aglsoft.com/punjabi/converter/) which knows about some common symbol fonts. If the font you want is in that list, you could try to extract the lookup table by pasting in all the characters in the range 32–126;128–255 (``` !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_``abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ ```) and grabbing what comes out when converted to ‘Unicode’.

Do you need to do the conversion in the application itself? If so you will typically need to write a character-by-character lookup loop. If not, best to use a tool like this manually to convert the material you want into standard Unicode, because dealing with text encoded in arbitrary symbol fonts is a pain in the neck.